# Using two modals

Tags: javascript, overlay

I'm sure this is a really simple issue but I'm having trouble opening two modal windows with javascript.

Desired effect would be for each button to open their own modal

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/22eg95bu/)

HTML

```
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h2>Modal 1</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal-2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h2>Modal 2</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="modalBtn-1">Modal 1</button>
<button id="modalBtn-2">Modal 2</button>
```

JS

```
// Get the modal 1
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-1');

var btn = document.getElementById("modalBtn-1");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: why re-invent wheel when you can use bootstrap modal ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were having was the second functions were overwriting the events for the first one.

If you had to do more than 2 modals you may want to consider modifying functions to be more universal

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modalBtn-1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}



// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modalBtn-2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  margin: 10% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  max-width: 800px; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-content {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
h2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h2>Modal 1</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal-2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="box-content">
      <h2>Modal 2</h2>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="modalBtn-1">Modal 1</button>
<button id="modalBtn-2">Modal 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @happymacarts, do you have any advice on how to write it to be more universal?

Comment: If you found it useful and it solved your issue accept the answer. But to make it more universal instead of adding the events to ids use a class and maybe use data-attributes.

Comment: Decided to learn Bootstrap and use that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good idea for bootstrap, it makes a lot of things easier, even tho the markup can get weighty.